# "Add to cart" button not working virtuemart 2 - joomla 2.5

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I have recently moved my site from a local server to a test server on-line. I noticed when I made the change, my "Add to cart" button stopped working. I know if has something to do with conflicting javascript or Ajax. I really need to get this fixed please help.

Here is the link to the TEST site.

http://mackeyshotrods.com/test/store/rvca-detail

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the same origin policy viloation

add the below code to your  server side ie. php page

```
   <?php 
    header('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 
    ?>
```

Comment: Same origin policy viloation??

Comment: How do I add the below code to my server side ie. php page? How do I locate it?

Comment: at the root of the site or every page?

Comment: to the page your are passing the ajax request

Comment: I'm using Joomla 2.5 my store is in a theme. I have many php pages for the store. I've tryed it on the index.php page of the template, the product_details.php page and etc... still not working? any other ideas?

Comment: @ijustchill, do you have a 'url' attribute in $.ajax

Answer (score 0):

This problem was occurring for me because the .htaccess was directing to 'http://www.mywebsite.com' (i.e. with www. prefix) and virtuemart/security/'security site url' and 'secure url' were set as 'http://mywebsite.com' (i.e. without www. prefix). Thus causing the same origin policy issue. Changing the virtuemart/security/'security site url' and 'secure url' to 'http://www.mywebsite.com' (so they matched) fixed this problem for me.